# Did the Edit standard action on User get renamed in Winter '15?

Tags: user, winter15

Did SalesForce rename the Edit standard action on **User** from **Edit** to **EditUserRecord**? The [release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm) don't mention anything about this.

Some of my deployments started failing over the weekend with the error:

> Error: objects/User.object(User):Edit is not a standard action and
>   cannot be overridden.

When I do a refresh from server the `actionOverrides` on `User` changes from this:

```
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>Edit</actionName>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

to this:

```
<actionOverrides>
    <actionName>EditUserAction</actionName>
    <type>Default</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

Comment: Did you change the metadata version of your toolkit/package.xml? If not, no change should have been visible to you. However, that said, it's generally a good idea to never mix versions when you can avoid it (e.g. if you retrieve v32, don't try to deploy to a v31 org).

Comment: Nothing changed in the metadata/package.xml. Our Continuous Integration system had a failing build over the weekend when the org was changed to WInter '15.  No code changes had been mad at all.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem.  All I did to get the build back is to do a 'manually' apply that change from 'Edit' to 'EditUserAction' on the User object, check in and rebuild.

The build failed when it's thinking that you're attempting to change the actionName.  Yes, looks like SF did change that field.  You didn't.  But if you want the build to go through, match with what SF is expecting.